# selectOneMenu pass in previous selection

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{bean.type}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{bean.Items}"        
        var="val" itemLabel="#{val.description}"
        itemValue="#{val.id}" />
    <p:ajax  process="@this" listener="#{bean.resetStart}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

In the bean,

```
public void resetStart() {
    if (type.equals("A")) {
        start = 0;
    }
}
```

What I want is when selecting a item with type "A", reset start to 0.
But the reality is it always does the purpose one step behind. E.g. when I select the option with type "A", it does nothing. Then I select anything else, it does the changes (now the type equals A).

Please let me know where the issue is. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a separate listender, simply try:

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{bean.type}">
  <p:ajax partialSumbit="true" process="@this"/>
```

and in your bean:

```
setType(String t) {
  type=t;
  if (type.equals("A"))
    start = 0;
}
```

Comment: it works. i think the key here is to use partialSubmit. Thanks!